# What is a visual proof of the formulas $\cot(A-B)$ and $\cot(A+B)$?

Tags: trigonometry

> What is a visual proof of the formulas for $\cot(A-B)$ and $\cot(A+B)$?

I am looking for visual proof of trig identities. So, please explain mentioned trig identities in geometric way.

Comment: Are we allowed to start from visual proofs of compound-angle formulae for other trigonometric functions, then use true-by-definition identities such as $\cot X=\frac{\cos X}{\sin X}$.

Comment: See the third figure in the collection in the ["Angle sum and difference identites"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) section of Wikipedia's ["List of trigonometric identities" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities).

Answer (score 2):

Start of proof: If you want a visual proof of, say, an identity like $\cot(A+B)=\cdots$, then the most natural thing to do would be to draw a right triangle where one angle is $A+B$, and from that angle draw a line segment to the opposite leg that makes an angle $A$. You now have two right triangles, one within the other, one with angle $A$, one with angle $A+B$, and you're ready to start calculating the ratios of sides to get an identity.